# ZSH Completions based on a directory, works after only after 'exec zsh'

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

for example, when i start terminal and type `brew install spot`

and press TAB - nothing, only dir like a `Desktop/`, but when i `exec zsh` everything magically starts working

Comment: Does completion work after entering `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` in a new terminal window?

Comment: no :( check this [video](https://imgur.com/a/zeONMBq)

Comment: Another thing to try: source the .zshrc file a second time (the first time happens when you log in): `. ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: it doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm afraid I am out of simple things to try. You may need to rebuild the various [dot files](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files) one item at a time try to isolate the issue. The symptoms you are reporting seem to be related to `compinit`; the call to `compinit` may be buried somewhere in the `oh-my-zsh` code.

Comment: [fix](https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion#configuring-completions-in-zsh)

Comment: Cool - glad you found it. That may be something you could type up as an answer here to help the next person who comes across it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add it to your `.zshrc`:

```
if type brew &>/dev/null
    then
      FPATH="$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh/site-functions:${FPATH}"
    
      autoload -Uz compinit
      compinit
    fi
```